# Pycharm can not read some codes. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIdAn.png)As you can see in the image, in the Pycharm, some codes are not light on... lilke line2 or line 5 , etc.

line 2 import sys

line 5 import csv

Do you know the reason?

```
# Need this for language determination
import sys

# Need this for reading csv file
import csv

# Need this for converting all texts into lowercase
import re

# Need this for tokenization
from nltk import wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
```

Comment: "some codes can not be read" - what exactly does that mean? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: Is there any usage of these packages in your code. I guess you are importing them and they are unused in the code

Comment: "some codes can not be read" means some codes are not light on.

Comment: @AnandTripathi It is my first time to use import sys in my Pycharm, but I used it in the JupyterNotebook

Comment: just next to that line type `sys.version` then then it will light on. It is not lighting on because that package is unused in your code

Comment: @AnandTripathi ye!!~~Now light on! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install some packages before you import them. Try with:

```
pip install os-sys
```

And so on with the other python packages.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! However, it worked at the JupyterNote so I thought sys installed already. Is it possible that sys is not working in Pycharm even it is working in JupyterNote?

Comment: If it's installed, it would work anywhere. Try to check your interpreter inside the PyCharm settings. It will show you every package installed for that interpreter.